# after successful deploying angular jS project build in tomcat 8 when i try to access the application its not showing blank page

Tags: java, angularjs, tomcat8

after successful deploying angular jS project build in tomcat 8 when i try to access the application its not showing blank page do i need to change anything in my index.html

My index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/dist/angular-datepicker.min.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/progress.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/navigation.css">

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/navigataur.css">-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/src/css/angular-datepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-spinkit/build/angular-spinkit.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-textAngular/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-textAngular/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome-animation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-textAngular/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome-animation.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


    <!-- endbuild -->


  </head>
```

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="Project\etyping_clienthttp://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

</div> -->

```
   <!--  <div  style="color: white; width: 100%; height:25px; font-size:14px;z-index:9999" id="footer" prevent-right-click>
    <div class="text-center" style="position:relative;top:1px;">Copyright © 2017.  All rights reserved | Designed and Developed by : <a target="blank" href="http://winnersoft.co.in/Contactus.html">
    <span style="color:white; font-size:15px;"> Winner Software Pvt.Ltd </span></a></div>

  </div> -->



    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/dist/angular-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-spinkit/build/angular-spinkit.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

 <route-loading-indicator>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAoZJOhlWq40H8_Y5R7qmVkvDiISVu8-fQ"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ng-table/ng-table.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-textAngular/textAngular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-textAngular/textAngular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/FileSaver.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="bower_components/angular-multi-select/angular-multi-select.js"></script> 
    <script src="bower_components/ng-camera/dist/ng-camera.js"></script> 
    <script src="bower_components/webcamjs/webcam.js"></script> 
    <script src="bower_components/ng-fullscreen/ng-fullscreen.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularjs-datepicker/src/js/angular-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-spinkit/build/angular-spinkit.min.js"></script>
     <script src="bower_components/angular-ng-storage/ngStorage.js"></script>

    <!--  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
     <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/controllers/Login.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/navigation.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/count.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/todoList_ctrl.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/controllers/taskHistory_ctrl.js"></script>
       <script src="scripts/controllers/proj_ctrl.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/service/LoginService.js"></script>


    <script src="scripts/controllers/home.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/service/homeService.js"></script>
     <script src="scripts/service/home1Service.js"></script>
     <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

     <script src="scripts/controllers/Registration.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/service/RegistrationService.js"></script> -->

     </route-loading-indicator>    
</body>

</html>
```

MY folder structure ofter Grunt build and copied in webapp folder.

please suggest me is there any way to deploy

[[image: ]]

This page is deployed webpage console file

Comment: can you go to the web page you deployed, and paste the results of console (in dev tools) here?

Comment: console file is added

Comment: All the resource files are throwing 404 . Check the paths.